# Finding 5 in a row

Tags: ios, objective-c

Background:
Im building a game "kinda" like connect 4. 
I have most of it working, the only part I'm stuck at now is determining if there are 5 of the same colors in a row (left,right,up,down & diagonal)

Question:

How can I get the code to loop and see if there are 5 pieces in a row with the same color in any direction.

Note - Each turn is played by moving one piece on the board to a new position and than 3 new pieces come into play. 
That means that it would have to check for a match of 5 after the turn and also after the 3 new pieces get randomly placed onto the board.

Thank you!

My code for the game so far is..

ViewController(.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BoardCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *imageNames;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *board;
@property NSInteger lastMove;
#define BOARDWIDTH 9
#define BOARDHEIGHT 9

@end

static int moves[]={-BOARDWIDTH,-1,1,BOARDWIDTH};
bool preSelect;
BoardCell *startCell;
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    preSelect = NO;
    self.imageNames = @[@"marble_red",@"marble_blue",@"marble_purple",@"marble_orange",@"marble_green"];

    self.board = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int y=0; y < BOARDWIDTH; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARDHEIGHT; x++) {
            UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(5+ 35 * x, 100 + 35 * y, 30, 30);
            button.tag = y*BOARDWIDTH+x;
                //[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", button.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.selected = NO;
            [button.layer setCornerRadius:15];
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.7 alpha:.5]];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview: button];
            [self.board addObject:[[BoardCell alloc] initWithButton:button]];
        }
    }

    self.lastMove=arc4random_uniform(BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT);
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:self.lastMove];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greensquare"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self addRandoms:3];


}

-(void) addRandoms:(NSInteger)randomCount {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomCount; i++) {
        int space = arc4random_uniform(BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT);
        BoardCell *cell=self.board[space];
        if (!cell.occupied) {
            int pic = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.imageNames.count);
            NSString *string = [self.imageNames objectAtIndex:pic];
            NSString *highlighted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_highlighted",string];
            NSLog(@"HIGHLIGHTED = %@",highlighted);
            [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            cell.button.selected = NO;
            cell.occupied=YES;
        }
        else {
            i--;
        }

    }
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSInteger buttonId=button.tag;
    BoardCell *cell=self.board[buttonId];
    if (!preSelect) {
        if (cell.occupied) {
                //cell.button.selected = YES;
            [[cell.button layer] setBorderWidth:3.5f];
            [cell.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:.85 alpha:.7]CGColor]];
            cell.button.highlighted = YES;
            preSelect = YES;
            self.lastMove = buttonId;
            startCell = cell;
        }else{
        cell.button.selected = NO;
            cell.button.highlighted = NO;
            [cell.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor]];

        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"SECOND STEP");
        if (!cell.occupied) {

            BoardCell *startCell=self.board[self.lastMove];
            startCell.occupied=NO;
            if ([self validMoveFromSquare:self.lastMove toDestination:buttonId]) {
                [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[startCell.button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [startCell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                NSLog(@"FROM %ld, TO %ld",(long)self.lastMove,(long)buttonId);
                    cell.button.selected = NO;
                cell.button.highlighted = NO;
                    startCell.button.selected = NO;
                startCell.button.highlighted = NO;
                self.lastMove=buttonId;
                cell.occupied=YES;
                preSelect = NO;
                [self addRandoms:3];

            }else{
            startCell.occupied=YES;
            preSelect = NO;
            cell.button.selected = NO;
            cell.button.highlighted = NO;
                    startCell.button.selected = NO;
            startCell.button.highlighted = NO;
            NSLog(@" INVALID FROM %ld, TO %ld",(long)self.lastMove,(long)buttonId);
            }
        }
        preSelect = NO;
        cell.button.selected = NO;
        cell.button.highlighted = NO;
        startCell.button.selected = NO;
        startCell.button.highlighted = NO;
        [cell.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor]];
        [startCell.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor]];


    }

}


-(BOOL) validMoveFromSquare:(NSInteger)startSquare toDestination:(NSInteger)destination {

    for (int limit=1;limit<10;limit++ ) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *visitList=[NSMutableIndexSet new];
        if ([self DFSFromStart:startSquare toGoal:destination withLimit:limit andVisitList:visitList]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;

}

-(BOOL) DFSFromStart:(NSInteger)start toGoal:(NSInteger)goal withLimit:(NSInteger)limit andVisitList:(NSMutableIndexSet *)visitList {



    if (limit >=0) {

        if (((BoardCell *)self.board[start]).occupied) {
            NSLog(@"Self Board = %@",self.board[start]);
            return NO;
        }

        [visitList addIndex:start];

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            NSInteger nextPosition=start+moves[i];
            NSLog(@"Next spot = %ld",(long)nextPosition);
            if (nextPosition == goal) {
                return YES;
            }
            if (nextPosition >=0 && nextPosition < BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT) {
                if (![visitList containsIndex:nextPosition]) {
                    if ([self DFSFromStart:nextPosition toGoal:goal withLimit:limit-1 andVisitList:visitList]) {
                        return YES;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return NO;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

BoardCell.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BoardCell : NSObject


@property (weak,nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *button;
@property BOOL occupied;


-(id) initWithButton:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive algorithm to work in each of the eight directions until you hit a boundary or a different color -

```
-(void) clearRunsOfColor:(Colors)color fromPoint:(NSInteger)startPoint {
    NSInteger left=[self runFromStart:startPoint-1 ofColor:color inDirection:-1];
    NSInteger right=[self runFromStart:startPoint+1 ofColor:color inDirection:1];
    BOOL cleared=NO;
    if (left+right+1 >4) {
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint-1 inDirection:-1 forLength:left];
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint+1 inDirection:1 forLength:right];
        cleared=YES;
    }

    NSInteger up=[self runFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH ofColor:color inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH];
    NSInteger down=[self runFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH ofColor:color inDirection:BOARDWIDTH];
    if (up+down+1 > 4) {
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH forLength:up];
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH inDirection:BOARDWIDTH forLength:down];
        cleared=YES;
    }

    NSInteger NW=[self runFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH-1 ofColor:color inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH-1];
    NSInteger SE=[self runFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH+1 ofColor:color inDirection:+BOARDWIDTH+1];

    if (NW+SE+1 > 4) {
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH-1 inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH-1 forLength:NW];
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH+1 inDirection:BOARDWIDTH+1 forLength:SE];
        cleared=YES;
    }

    NSInteger NE=[self runFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH+1 ofColor:color inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH+1];
    NSInteger SW=[self runFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH-1 ofColor:color inDirection:+BOARDWIDTH-1];

    if (NE+SW+1 > 4) {
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint-BOARDWIDTH+1 inDirection:-BOARDWIDTH+1 forLength:NE];
        [self clearBoardFromStart:startPoint+BOARDWIDTH-1 inDirection:BOARDWIDTH-1 forLength:SW];
        cleared=YES;
    }

    if (cleared) {
        [self occupyCell:startPoint withPiece:nil];
    }
}

-(void) clearBoardFromStart:(NSInteger)start inDirection:(NSInteger)direction forLength:(NSInteger) length {
    NSInteger pos=start;
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        [self occupyCell:pos withPiece:nil];
        pos+=direction;
    }

}

-(NSInteger) runFromStart:(NSInteger)start ofColor:(Colors)color inDirection:(NSInteger)direction {
    if ([self inBounds:start]) {
        BoardCell *thisCell=self.board[start];
        if (thisCell.gamepiece != nil && thisCell.gamepiece.color == color) {
            if ([self validDestination:start+direction withMove:(int)direction fromSquare:start]) {
                return ([self runFromStart:start+direction ofColor:color inDirection:direction]+1);
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

-(BOOL) inBounds:(NSInteger) position {
    if (position >=0 && position < BOARDHEIGHT*BOARDWIDTH) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect except it doesn't recognize the top left corner as a space . So if it's 5 in a row from the top left corner it won't detect 5 in a row.. Could be with other corners also but this is the one I've found so far.. Any idea?

Comment: There was a bug in the `inBounds` method - it should be >= 0

Comment: If I wanted to create different levels in this game. Would I create a Levels Class? The levels would change based on How many different kinds of pieces there are.. Number of spaces (8x8..9x9..), required score to win.. things like that

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of refactoring you could do - having the game engine in the `ViewController` isn't a very good design.  I would abstract the board into a `Board` class (so you would hold a reference to a Board object rather than the array as it is now).  When you initialise the Board you would specify the size.  You would need to replace all of the `BOARDWIDTH` `BOARDHEIGHT` #define references to the property for width & height.  You would add any other properties you needed as well (target score for example).

Comment: If you wanted to store the level definitions in some store (Core Data or a Plist) then it would make sense to create a Level class that represented the data that was loaded into memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69419/discussion-between-user3080828-and-paulw11).

Comment: @user3080828 check chat

Comment: Added images and Logo

Comment: @Paulw11check chat, big bug

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry for the bother. If you just wanted to know what it was. When you drag a piece to an invalid space, the piece returns and than disappears. Sorry again for the bother

Answer (score 0):

*None of the code below is tested for correctness.*

You could update your `BoardCell` class like so:

```
typedef enum {
  TopLeft,    Top,    TopRight,
  Left,               Right,
  BottomLeft, Bottom, BottomRight,
  NumberOfDirections
} BoardCellAdjacentDirection;

@interface BoardCell
- (void)addAdjacentCell:(BoardCell *)cell forDirection:(BoardCellAdjacentDirection)direction;
- (NSInteger)occupiedCellsInDirection:(BoardCellAdjacentDirection)direction;
@end

@implementation BoardCell {
  NSMutableArray *adjacentCells;
}
- (instancetype)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    adjacentCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < (NSInteger)NumberOfDirections; i++) {
      [adjacentCells addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
- (void)addAdjacentCell:(BoardCell *)cell forDirection:(BoardCellAdjacentDirection)direction {
  [adjacentCells setObject:cell atIndex:(NSInteger)direction];
}
- (NSInteger)occupiedCellsInDirection:(BoardCellAdjacentDirection)direction {
  if (!self.occupied) return 0;
  if (adjacentCells[direction] == [NSNull null]) return 1;
  return [adjacentCells[direction] occupiedCellsInDirection:direction]+1;
}
@end
```

Wherever you create your `BoardCell` objects, you'll need to add the appropriate adjacent cells. You'll also probably want to put in some sanity checks to make sure that cell adjacency is a two-way relationship (i.e. cell A is left-adjacent to B and B is right-adjacent to A).

**Edit** You'll probably also want to add a method to determine if you've injected a cell into the centre of a line.

```
typedef enum {
  BackSlash,
  ForwardSlash,
  Vertical,
  Horizontal
} BoardCellAxis;

...

- (NSInteger)occupiedCellsOnAxis:(BoardCellAxis)axis {
  switch (axis) {
  case BackSlash:
    return MAX(0, [self occupiedCellsInDirection:TopLeft]
                  + [self occupiedCellsInDirection:BottomRight]
                  - 1); // Don't count yourself twice.
  case ForwardSlash:
    return MAX(0, [self occupiedCellsInDirection:TopRight]
                  + [self occupiedCellsInDirection:BottomLeft]
                  - 1); // Don't count yourself twice.
  case Vertical:
    return MAX(0, [self occupiedCellsInDirection:Top]
                  + [self occupiedCellsInDirection:Bottom]
                  - 1); // Don't count yourself twice.
  case Horizontal:
    return MAX(0, [self occupiedCellsInDirection:Left]
                  + [self occupiedCellsInDirection:Right]
                  - 1); // Don't count yourself twice.
  }
}
```

Comment: Im still beginning Xcode so I might be asking stupid questions but does this check that the pieces next to the move that you moved are the same color or just that those spaces are occupied as well? Also do I need to place any code in my View Controller? Thanks!

Comment: This only checks if they're occupied. You would have to modify the `occupiedCellsInDirection` to match a specific colour. Because it's data-related, your colour should be stored as part of your `BoardCell`. You would need to execute `occupiedCellsInDirection:` wherever you want to know how many cells are occupied in a specific direction starting from a specific `BoardCell`. If this is in your view controller, then yes, you'll need to put code in your view controller.

Comment: Im sorry I don't really understand how this works or how to implement it in the way I would need. If you would explain it more id be very thankful as this is a key part of my app, otherwise Thank you anyways.